# Looping through gridview and change certain column font colour

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a gridview and I wanted to make certain columns text a different colour... i.e every column that says actual I want this text to be green... can anybody help? My gridlooks similar to this.

```
Hour - actual A - target A - actual aa - target aa - actual b - target b.
```

And finally is there a way to reset the data in my gridview after a certain amount of time... i.e `shiftstart 6am-2pm 2pm-10pm 10pm-6am`... So the data refreshes after 8 hours back to zero.

```
   public void Refreshdata(int selectedProduct, DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd)
        {
            BizManager biz = new BizManager();

            GridView1.DataSource = biz.GetPacktstatisticsForShift(
                shiftStart
                , shiftEnd
                , selectedProduct).DefaultView;
            GridView1.DataBind();

 public DataTable CreatePackingStats(DataSet dset)
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                DataTable target = dset.Tables[0];

                DataTable actual = dset.Tables[1];

                DataColumn[] cols = new DataColumn[1];
                cols[0] = actual.Columns["Hour"];
                actual.PrimaryKey = cols;

                DataTable final = new DataTable();



                // Create table columns
                foreach (DataColumn col in target.Columns)
                {
                    final.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, col.DataType));
                    if (col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                    {
                        // Add an equivilant actual column
                        string newColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace("Target", "Actual");
                        final.Columns.Add(newColumnName, col.DataType);
                    }
                }
                //// Add rows to new table
                foreach (DataRow row in target.Rows)
                {
                    string key = row["Hour"].ToString();

                    DataRow newRow = final.Rows.Add();
                    // Store column value
                    foreach (DataColumn col in final.Columns)
                    {


                        if (col.ColumnName.Contains("HOUR") || col.ColumnName.Contains("Target"))
                        {
                            newRow[col.ColumnName] = row[col.ColumnName];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Find actual data
                            DataColumn actColumn = actual.Columns[col.ColumnName] as DataColumn;
                            if (actColumn == null)
                            {
                                newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString()))
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newRow[col.ColumnName] = actual.Rows.Find(key)[col.ColumnName].ToString();
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
                return final;
```

The `CreatePackingStats` is populating my grid with added columns FYI.

I guess there is a way to add colour text whilst the code is looping through the data and creating extra columns, not sure how to do this tho.?

And also the `CreatePackingStats` is located in a class and not in the page behind aspx.

Sorry about all the questions I am new and learning, all your help will help to develop and I appreciate all the help I receive.

Comment: On `GridView` there is an event called `RowDataBound`, you can use that event to check the value and change the `ForeColor` of your particular cell.

Comment: cool, do you know where about i need to do this and the coding i need please>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on your `GridView` then go to the `properties` tab and select `events`.In there you will find the event called `RowDataBound`.

In that event write your code to change the `forecolor` like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //here the Cells is an array where you can pass the index value of the cell where you want to check and if you don't know where the value is then you can do a for loop and then check the value
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "someValue")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Update 1** for comparing the value using the **IndexOf()**

As for the data what you have given, you have to change the compare function from `==` to `IndexOf("SomeValue")`.For that, you can try the `IndexOf("actual")`. If it gives `value > -1` then change the `color`.
or you can try the below code where I am looping through all the `columns` in the `row`(you can try to avoid the looping if you have knowledge on which column the value will occur):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().IndexOf("actual") > -1)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

> **Update 2** Adding the snapshots of sample data and it's output.

Here is the sample data with which I am working:
[image]

And here is the processed output using the `IndexOf()` loop over the in `RowDataBound` event.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @DomBolton if you are having value in your `column` as `actual a` and not `actual` then you can use updated code for `IndexOf()`.

Comment: No unfortunately this has not changed anything, not sure if its because my code is done in the create packing stats method, but i tryed i in the rowdatabound event, but nothing is changing :(

Comment: can you put a breakpoint on the `RowDataBound()` event and check if it is getting triggered and if yes what value are you getting.

Comment: Its triggering fine and looping through the cells nut nothing is changing for some reason

Comment: I do apologise, this code actually works if i am looking for values in a cell, but what i need it to do it actually change the text of each column that starts with actual... any advice. thanks so far, your help has been great.

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().IndexOf("", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
            }

Comment: If text is what you only want to update then you can check for the data at the data source end and replace it with what you want.

Comment: not sure how to do this, i just wanted certain columns text to be the color red, i have 4 actual columns, and four target columns.. and i just wanted to highlights the actual columns.. but when i put 0 then all the columns with 0 turn red at the moment.

Comment: @DomBolton check the 2nd Update that I have included with the snapshot of the data used in the looping. And keep in mind right now the deciding condition is based on the string `actual`, you can change it with your desired one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, what i actually need is this below https://ibb.co/iv7Avy

Comment: actual column... all writing in red... and target column all text in green

Comment: @DomBolton are the columns index(i.e their position) fixed and what is the criteria to color the columns text?

Comment: yes. we started with actual columns and then added the target colums after... So the two columns are coming from two seperate tables like this...  and the code is looping to add the targets and actuals together.. but they will never move from here.

Comment: @DomBolton you can do that by setting the column index in the code. Suppose the column with text `actual` is at index 2(as they start from 0) then you can change the code in the `RowDataBound()` as `e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red` instead of the looping and do change in the respective code for other columns as well with your desired condition.

Comment: Cool, that worked -   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text.ToLower().IndexOf("0") > -1)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    } So how would i add new rows into my code... sorry for so many questions :)

Comment: i mean so i can put all the actual rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171980/discussion-between-vikscool-and-dom-bolton).